# resource type error while trying to use cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I tried to use the exact same example provided in the user guide mentioned below. **It works from console but fails to create stack using client.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-namedquery.html

I got an error while trying to execute the following:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "AthenaNamedQuery": {
      "Type": "AWS::Athena::NamedQuery",
      "Properties": {
        "Database": "swfnetadata",
        "Description": "A query that selects all aggregated data",
        "Name": "MostExpensiveWorkflow",
        "QueryString": "SELECT workflowname, AVG(activitytaskstarted) AS AverageWorkflow FROM swfmetadata WHERE year='17' AND GROUP BY workflowname ORDER BY AverageWorkflow DESC LIMIT 10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is the "create-stack" parameter of cloudformation correct?

> aws cloudformation create-stack  --stack-name dnd --template-body file://final.json

Why am I getting a resource type error like this?

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Athena::NamedQuery]
```

Comment: I would suggest check/update your CLI version. Either way do let know if that works

Comment: Were you able to create the named query using the command mentioned above @ASR ?

Comment: @ASR you can post your comment as answer if you are interested in bounty :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Though not really worth as an answer. Silly things happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when I updated my CLI version as suggested in the comment. This issue is now closed.