# AWS listener cf template gives error in aws cli but is valid in console(design template)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I am trying to create 2 listeners for the load balancer.

1st - HTTP for redirecting and 2nd - HTTPS for forwarding.

I am trying to achieve this via cf template. Everytime I execute the stack in console via design template, it is validated successfully. But when I try the same stack with aws cli, I get the following error.

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ApplicationLoadBalancer] in the Resources block of the template

Following is the code sample for listener and LB.

```
"ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Condition": "NeedELB",
      "Properties": {
        "Subnets": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "VpcStack",
              "Outputs.PublicSubnet1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "VpcStack",
              "Outputs.PublicSubnet2"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroups": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "VpcStack",
              "Outputs.ELBSecurityGroup"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Stack",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
            }
          },
          {
            "Key": "FargateCluster",
            "Value": {
              "Ref": "FargateECSCluster"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "LoadBalancerHTTPListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "Type": "redirect",
            "RedirectConfig": {
              "Host": "#{host}",
              "Path": "/#{path}",
              "Port": "443",
              "Protocol": "HTTPS",
              "Query": "#{query}",
              "StatusCode": "HTTP_302"
            }
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
          "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": "80",
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
      ]
    },
    "LoadBalancerListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Condition": "NeedELB",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [
          {
            "Type": "forward",
            "TargetGroupArn": {
              "Ref": "DefaultTargetGroup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn": {
          "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
        },
        "Port": "443",
        "Protocol": "HTTPS",
        "Certificates": [
          {
            "CertificateArn": {
              "Fn::If": [
                "NeedTLSEndPoint",
                {
                  "Ref": "SSLCertificateArn"
                },
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "DependsOn": [
        "DefaultTargetGroup",
        "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
      ]
    }
```

Please help me out with the validation error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a change in condition `NeedELB` when you create from CLI? I see that resource `LoadBalancerHTTPListener` depends on `ApplicationLoadBalancer` which is created conditionally. If `NeedELB` is false, stack might still try to create `LoadBalancerHTTPListener`. Either way you should add that condition for `LoadBalancerHTTPListener`.

PS: Try updating your CLI. Older CLI version can cause this. Case in point [resource-type-error-while-trying-to-use-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060734/resource-type-error-while-trying-to-use-cloudformation)

Comment: I am getting the same error even if i updated the cli with pip3. Can you suggest any other way to resolve the issue?

Comment: It worked out. Thanks a ton! I can't believe I was overlooking the condition. You can edit your answer so that I can mark that as correct. @ASR